# Protractor: desired capabilities for creating a fake web cam stream

Tags: protractor, katalon-studio

I want to create a fake video/web cam stream for a protractor unit test. The below code, is  the current desired capabilities. They work perfectly in the command line and I have experimented with paths to the the file sample.y4m but have not succeeded in getting it to work. In fact the same code works in a Katalon project.

`capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {'args': ['--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=documents/sample.y4m']}
  },`

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly, the only problem was specifying the file path without using escape characters. Silly mistake but here the corrected version would be `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=documents//sample.y4m.`